# swift typealias with protocol issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift-protocols, type-alias

I want to have a type of UIView that conforms to my custom protocol. I try to do it like this, but Xcode says that it's not a proper declaration:

```
typealias ViewThatConformsToProtocol = UIView: MyCustomProtocol
```

and this doesn't work too:

```
typealias ViewThatConformsToProtocol = UIView, MyCustomProtocol
```

But I don't want to use subclasses for that. Is it any way to do that?

**P.S.**
With subclassing I would it like this:

```
class ViewThatConformsToProtocol: UIView, MyCustomProtocol {

}
```

But I don't want to use subclassing because it's against my design pattern  (for example because when I just need to know that my View supports the behaviou of this protocol, I don't want this view to subclass ViewThatConformsToProtocol . And sometimes View1 can confirm to Protocol1 and Protocol2, but View2 can conform to Protocol1 and Protocol3 - it's just for example). In Objective-C you could easily declare `UIView *viewForProtocol = (UIView<MyCustomProtocol> *)view1` , but in SWIFT it's seems impossible , so I'm looking for walk-around

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve. Can you show us how you would do it if you "used subclasses for that"?

Comment: @Sweeper , I have added the code and comments.

Comment: @MaxPevsner , this article didn't help

Comment: So you want a type alias that is `UIView` or a subclass of `UIview` _and_ it conforms to `MyCustomProtocol`?

Comment: @Sweeper , only UIView that conforms to MyCustomProtocol , not subclass of UIView

Comment: But there is only one class called `UIView`. This class either conforms to `MyCustomProtocol` or it does not. This can be determined at compile time.

Comment: @Sweeper , I understand , but how can I implement Objective-C UIView *viewForProtocol = (UIView<MyCustomProtocol> *)view1 in SWIFT?

Comment: Sorry, I can't read Objective-C code very well...

Answer (score 1):

```
typealias DesiredAlias<T> = T where T:MyCustomProtocol

//you can assign type like below
var variableThatConformsToProtocol: DesiredAlias<MyCustomProtocol>
```

Maybe that piece of code meets your requirements? Actually it takes any type that conforms to `MyCustomProtocol`, so it's similar to `id<MyCustomProtocol> variableThatConformsToProtocol` in `Objective-C`

Answer (score 0):

Actually @MaxPevsner's suggestion was right but not exact.
You don't need to use `typealias` since all the magic can do generics.

```
protocol MyCustomProtocol {
    // ...
}

class MyCustomView: UIView, MyCustomProtocol {

}

class MyClass<T> where T: MyCustomProtocol {

    func someFunction<T>(_ value: T) {
        self.property = value
    }
}

// ...
let view = MyCustomView()
let trick = MyClass<MyCustomView>()
trick.someFunction(view)
```

Does it fit your requirements?

Comment: actually no, because here we don't need AnotherCustomProtocol very much , because I need to do like in Objective-C UIView *viewForProtocol = (UIView<MyCustomProtocol> *)view1 in many methods (I'm converting Objective-C code into SWIFT)

Answer (score 0):

A typealias is an alias to a specific type. You are asking for something that conforms to a set of conditions

Given the code snippet you have posted

```
UIView *viewForProtocol = (UIView<MyCustomProtocol> *)view1
```

The equivalent swift code would be

```
let viewForProtocol = view1 as? MyCustomProtocol as ? UIView
```

Comment: Guess you either have a handle to a UIView or a MyCustomProtocol. You can't have both